# How to send a file to RasPi from different computers?

Tags: pi-3

It is first time for me working with RasPi.

I would like to send a file (if possible via mail in the form of attachments) to my RasPi, from one/more computers (which are connected via Wi-Fi).

Is it possible and, if so, how?

Comment: If they are not connected (to each other or a network), then put the files on a USB stick. But you mention mail, which makes it sound like they are in fact networked. Tell us more about how they're connected.

Comment: Could you please read and answer my previous questions? As it stands, your question does not make sense.

Comment: what i mean not connected is,they are not connected via LAN but can be connected by wifi .

Comment: So they are connected then. Wifi is LAN.

Comment: What is the other computer running? This may effect the answer (if some Unix, then it is easy, If Microsoft's windows then a little harder). Also where is the other computer: is it local or remote (over the internet)?

Comment: It is over the internet

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very confusing. Please edit it and try to explain it a bit more understandable. First you say computer are not connected, then they are connected by WiFi and now the computer are remote over the internet. That cannot be done with WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

You say your devices are not connected to the RasPi. Then the only way to transfer data to it is to use a physical medium like an USB stick. Another way you ask about for file transfer is by email attachment. This can only be done with an internet connection, either wired or by WiFi.

If you decide to use an ethernet connection then you can just connect your computer with an ethernet cable to the RasPi. The connection should work out of the box. You can also setup your RasPi as a WiFi access point. This way your computer can connect to the RasPi by WiFi but you have to configure WiFi on both devices.

If you have a connection then there are several ways to transfer files. You can use `scp` for single file transfer, or you can open a network share on the RasPi using `NFS` or `Samba` to give only some examples. To a network share you can connect with your computer and work with it like a normal folder. To transfer data as mail attachment it is some more effort. You can setup a mail server on the RasPi.

Or you just use a mail account from  your internet provider. Then you don't need a direct connection between computer and RasPi. But you need an internet connection of the RasPi and the computer to the mail account.

Answer (score 0):

To add additional information you may use netcat. Just type `nc -l -p 8888 > filename` into Raspberry Pi

and `filename > nc -w 3 <IP address of your RPi which you can find out with hostname -I> 8888` on the sender machine.

Please keep in mind that an assumption is made that your LAN network is secured, since netcat does NOT use encryption.